# Testing Laravel post requests using a Factory

Tags: laravel-5, tdd

I am writing some Feature tests for my Laravel application. I am new to TDD, so this may seem obvious to some.

**LocationsFactory.php**

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Location::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
    ];
});
```

**LocationsTest.php**

```
public function a_user_can_create_a_location(): void
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $user = factory(User::class)->make();
    $location = factory(Location::class)->make();


    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/locations', $location);  // $location needs to be an array

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('locations', ['name' => $location->name]);
}
```

> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::post() must be of the type array, object given

I understand the error is telling me that `$location` needs to be an array and it is an object. However, since I'm using a factory it's coming as an object. Is there a better way to use a factory in my test?

This also seems a bit off:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('locations', ['name' => $location->name]);
```

Since I am using faker, I have no idea what the `name` will be. So I'm just checking for whatever was generated is that ideal?

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Doing something like this works fine (and maybe that's the solution)...

```
...
$user = factory(User::class)->make();
$location = factory(Location::class)->make();

$response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/locations', [
    'name' => $location->name
]);

$response->assertStatus(200);
$this->assertDatabaseHas('locations', ['name' => $location->name]);
```

However, let's say my `location` has 30 attributes. That seems like it could get ugly quick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Laravel 5

Use `toArray()` for object to array conversion : see following example

```php
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();
    $location = factory(Location::class)->make();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/locations', $location->toArray());

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('locations', ['name' => $location->name]);
```

Comment: I  thought I had tried that, but clearly did no implement it correctly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `raw` which will build up the attributes as an array.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->make();
$location = factory(Location::class)->raw();

$response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/locations', $location);

$response->assertStatus(200);
$this->assertDatabaseHas('locations', $location);
```